# File/Code location to disable & delete item in Magento?

Tags: file, magento, product

I am looking for **code location** of product **disabling** in magento & also for **deleting** items from Magento?

What is the **file/function** name for the same?

How can we get disabling or deleting product id on that page?

At backend we can **delete product in 2 ways**-:

1. by selecting multiple items &  then submit action as delete
2. opening each individual item & then delete that item

Does for both these code/function is same? If not, please provide me code/file location for both ways..

Please guide me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code location to disable & delete Customer in Magento?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726435/code-location-to-disable-delete-customer-in-magento) // User has superseded this question with another.

Answer (score 0):

For the massive delete product feature, you may find this function in the class: Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController, with action: massDeleteAction().

And also you may find the deleteAction() in the same controller to delete an individual product.

Hope this is helpful to you.