# Code location to disable & delete Customer in Magento?

Tags: magento

Can we **disable**  **customer** in magento? If yes, where is the code location for the same?

Also, where is the code/file location for **deleting** customers from Magento?

What is the **file/function** name for the same?

How can we get disable or deleted **customer id** on that page?

At backend we can **delete customer in 2 ways**-:

```
1. By selecting multiple customer &  then submit action as delete
2. Opening each indivual customer & then delete that customer
```

Does for both these code/function is same? If not, please provide me code/file location for both ways.

Please guide me!

Answer (score 0):

`Mage_Core_Model_Abstract()->delete($id)`.